# Doubt in understanding a question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question: How many different letter permutations, of any length, can be made using the letters M O T T O. (For instance, there are 3 possible permutations of length 1.)

Hey guys, I was busy attempting this problem, but I am confused on in 3 where XXYZ in 2C1 × 4! ÷ 2! why do we have to multiply by 2C1. I understand the reasoning behind everything else except for this. Thanks.

1 Three ways i.e. {M,T,O}

2 XX or XY XX in 2C1 = two ways i.e. {OO or TT} XY in 3C2 × 2! = six ways

3 XXY or XYZ XXY in 2C1 × 2C1 × 3! ÷ 2! = twelve ways XYZ in 3C3 × 3! = six ways

4 XXYY or XXYZ XXYY = 4! ÷ (2! × 2!) = six ways XXYZ in 2C1 × 4! ÷ 2! = twenty four ways

5 = 5! ÷ (2! ×2!) = 120 ÷ 4 = 30 Therefore, the total is = 3 + (2 +6)+ (12 +6) + (6 +24) + 30 = 89

Comment: The $2$ you are asking about comes because we want to choose whether it was the O that was repeated or if it was the T that was repeated.

Comment: That said, I disapprove of having written that step using a binomial coefficient.  Just because something *can* be written as a binomial coefficient doesn't mean you need to.  Choosing zero, choosing 1, choosing all but one, and choosing all... I'd sooner write as regular numbers.  $\binom{n}{0}=\binom{n}{n}=1$ and $\binom{n}{1}=\binom{n}{n-1}=n$.  Writing this as 2C1 or writing as 3C3 etc I think distracts from the counting.